# Jasper Report 4.5.0 + Struts + exporting pdf

Tags: struts, jasper-reports, report, ireport

Well I have been developing a web application with struts Framework and I'm using JasperReport 4.5.0 to show a pdf with some information that is inserted in the web. Well sorry if u can't understand me, but I don't speak english so much so... I'm trying to explain it in english.

The problem appears when I want to export to pdf some data. When I deploy the application in the localhost it works fine, but when I deploy it on the server, it shows an error.

**Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser**

I was searching on the web about the problem, but it say that there is a problem with the jars, but I don't know if any jars I'm missing, or it's another problem

please I need help, what can i do?

This is the video please watch it with 720(HD) better in full screen  thank you

[video about the problem that I have](http://youtu.be/pIB6E0Efl5w)

Answer (score 0):

We need the following files:

```
dist/jasperreports-X.jar
lib/commons-*.jar (all the commons - except maybe for commons-logging)
lib/itext-X.jar
lib/jdt-compiler.jar
```

Source :
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html